# Taking user input from different html and printing it

Tags: html, typescript, user-input

I am a beginning coder and am trying to get some user input from a different html and using it but it isnt working for me. I have been using document.getElementById but it just doesnt work. Probably a stupid mistake or something I am failing to see. I want the user to fill in their username in the first html and on the next page I want it to print Hello + username.

This is my HTML

```
<form style="margin-left: 630px; margin-top: 30px;" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="homepage.html" name="english_registration_form" id="english_registration_form">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" aria-describedby="name-format" required placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
    <span class="error"><p id="name_error"></p></span>
    <input type="wachtwoord" id="wachtwoord" name="wachtwoord" required placeholder="Wachtwoord">
    <span class="error"><p id="email_error"></p></span>
    <button onclick="greetings()" class="register_button" type="submit" value="submit">Registreren</button>
</form>
```

This is my typescript in other HTML

```
function greetings() {
    var ad = document.getElementById("name").value;

    Console.WriteLine("Hallo " + ad + "!");
}
```

If you need some more insight or if I was not clear. Tell me

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` isn't a TypeScript function. Where did you see that?

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong here.  (1) `Console` isn't defined, it looks like you're confusing C# with JavaScript.  (2) `validateForm` isn't defined, which would cause an error here.  (3) If `greetings` is defined on the second page then you can't reference it from the first page.  (4) If the `id="name"` element is defined on the first page then you can't reference it from the second page.  etc. etc.

Comment: Overall, you're currently sending a POST request to the second page, which means server-side code would access the posted `name` value.  If you change the form method to a GET then you can access query string values in JavaScript on that second page.  The two pages can't interact directly, any given page can only access what's on it or what data was sent to it.  Other options potentially include things like storing the value in local storage on the first page and retrieving it on the second page, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I already thought I made some stupid mistake. As I said, I am a beginner and dont really see whats usable and whats not! Thanks!